# Local disk configuration in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

Hi the official Spark documentation state:

> While Spark can perform a lot of its computation in memory, it still
>   uses local disks to store data that doesn’t fit in RAM, as well as to
>   preserve intermediate output between stages. We recommend having 4-8
>   disks per node, configured without RAID (just as separate mount
>   points). In Linux, mount the disks with the noatime option to reduce
>   unnecessary writes. In Spark, configure the spark.local.dir variable
>   to be a comma-separated list of the local disks. If you are running
>   HDFS, it’s fine to use the same disks as HDFS.

- **I wonder what is the purpose of 4-8 per node**

Is it for parallel write ? I am not sure to understand the reason why as it is not explained.

- **I have no clue for this: "If you are running HDFS, it’s fine to use
  the same disks as HDFS".**

Any idea what is meant here...

Answer (score 1):

Purpose of usage 4-8 RAID disks to mirror partitions adding redundancy to prevent data lost in case of fault on hardware level. In case of HDFS the redundancy that RAID provides is not needed, since HDFS handles it by replication between nodes.
[Reference](https://msahputra.wordpress.com/2014/10/03/hadoop-why-not-use-raid/)

Comment: I might not understand what you mean, but the official documentation says without RAID and your comment talks about having raid disk. 4 to 8 disk is without or without hdfs if I understand well. Hence your comment add a bit more confusion although the link is interesting indded

Comment: If an executor has 8 task then he better have 8 disk ? To mirror partition use ??

Comment: if you have hdfs configured with proper replication level there is no requirement for raid.